# What is the solution for the differential equation y''+y=arctanx using variation of parameters method?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I get stack at the integration of the parameters, for example, the first parameter goes something like that A'=cosx.arctanx

Comment: A fundamental set is $y_1=\cos(t),y_2=\sin(t)$, the associated Wronskian when writing them in that order is $1$, so you are asked to integrate $\cos(x) \arctan(x)$ and $\sin(x) \arctan(x)$. Neither of these integrals is elementary, though you can still write down a formula for the solution in terms of definite integrals with variable limits anyway.

Comment: thanks, i really appreciate that